# Ruby array to multi-dimensional array

Tags: ruby, arrays

Simple question.  I'm in Rails, and I have an array like this:

```
['a','b','c','d']
```

And I need to convert it to an array like this:

```
[[0,'a'],[1,'b'],[2,'c'],[3,'d']]
```

I think there's a name for that type of array, but I can't remember what it is so I can't Google it.  Help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple combination of [`each_with_index`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_index) and [`map`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-map) is all you need:

```
a.each_with_index.map { |e, i| [ i, e ] }
```

`each_with_index` to iterate over your array with indexes and then `map` to transform (or map) your data to the desired format.

The result is an "array of arrays". There are no 2D arrays in Ruby, just arrays of arrays (unless, I suppose, you want to include [`Matrix`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/matrix/rdoc/index.html) from the standard library but that's not an Array even if it sort of looks like one).